# invite Facebook friends to Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I am trying to send friends an invitation or request to visit a website I am building.

I have the following dialogue box which allows me to select the friends I wish to invite:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" id="invite_fb_friends">Invite your friends</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function(){
        FB.init({
        appId: '239473799421284',
        status: true,
        cookie: false,
        // xfbml: true
        });

FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: '<%=current_user.name %> has invite you to a party for <%=get_current_board.bp_name%>'});
});
});
</script>
```

This works fine and I send the invitation. However when the user clicks the accept button they just reload the same page they are on.

Here is the setup in Facebook for the Application:

Website

```
Site URL:http://localhost:3000/

Site Domain:localhost

App on Facebook
Canvas URL:http://localhost:3000/pages/facebook_invite/
```

How can I get this link to go to my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this posting [on stackoverflow Facebook Developers Section](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7198275/cannot-find-canvas-page-setting)

On the Facebook Application page [Edit Application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) they changed the name for the canvas page.

[image]

It is now called App Namespace and you must enter a unique name here. Then it all worked.